# PHP get parameters from URL and convert to array

Tags: php, arrays

**CASE:**

I'm trying to get ordered items and quantity from another page, so I'm passing it using GET (http://foo.bar/?view=process-order&itm=1&qty=1000...), then I must to take this parameters and convert to an multidimensional array following this sequence:

**EXPECTED:**

URL will be: http://foo.bar/?view=foo-bar&itm=1&qty=1000&itm=2&qty=3000&itm=3&qty=1850

```
[0]=>
   [itm]=>'1',
   [qty]=>'1000',
[1]=>
   [itm]=>'2',
   [qty]=>'3000',
[2]=>
   [itm]=>'3';
   [qty]=>'1850',
 etc.
```

**CODE:**

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; //get the URL
$items = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY); //get only the query from URL
$items = explode( '&', $items );//Explode array and remove the &
unset($items[0]); //Remove view request from array
$items = implode(",", $items); //Implode to a string and separate with commas
list($key,$val) = explode(',',$items); //Explode and remove the commas
$items = array($key => $val); //Rebuild array
```

**ACTUAL RESULT:**

```
[itm=1] => [qty=1000]
```

**ACTUAL BEHAVIOUR:**

Result leave only the first element in the array and make it like `array({[itm=1]=>[qty=1000]})` that anyway isn't what I need.
Even If I've read much pages of PHP docs can't find the solution.

Thanks to all who can help

Comment: You should use Session instead of get parameters

Comment: Put down a full example of what the url is going to look like for the 3 items in your 'Expected'.  I suspect you want to reuse the itm and qty names?  If so the answer is more complicated.

Comment: updated, I'll pass the variable concatenated, don't want to use the same items

Comment: Can please someone explain the down votes? I've read all the question guides line and provide many accurate questions I can, people read the discussion, down vote and go away?

Comment: sidenote: you can't have same field value pair values, it'll overwrite them only giving you one pair, use a grouping field name instead, ala `qty[0], qty[1]`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement `list($key,$val) = explode(',',$items);` will only fetch the first two items in an array.

Here's a rewritten version

```
$chunks = explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
$items = array();
$current = -1; // so that entries start at 0
foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
  $parts = explode('=', $chunk);
  if ($parts[0] == 'itm') {
    $current++;
    $items[$current]['itm'] = urldecode($parts[1]);
  }
  elseif ($parts[0] == 'qty') {
    $items[$current]['qty'] = urldecode($parts[1]);
  }
}

print_r($items);
```

Comment: I got this ˙Array ( [0] => Array ( [itm] => 2 [qty] => 2350 ) )˙

Comment: Even if is the expected behaviour, only return one item

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise parse_str doesn't handle the same key appearing multiple times.  I've updated my answer now, please check this version.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version. I only modified the bottom part of your code (first 4 lines are untouched).

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; //get the URL
$items = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY); //get only the query from URL
$items = explode('&', $items );//Explode array and remove the &
unset($items[0]); //Remove view request from array

$list = array(); // create blank array for storing data
foreach ($items as $item){
    list($key, $val) = explode('=', $item);
    if ($key === 'itm')
        $list[] = ['itm' => $val];
    else // qty
        $list[count($list) - 1]['qty'] = $val;
}
```

Hope this helps.